# Disabling browser javascript with Selenium webdriver + specflow + c# + Pageobject + pagefactory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow, pageobjects

I want to disable firefox javascript and run my automated test.

I am using Specflow + c# and selenium.

I am also using PageObject pattern and Page factory.

My feature file goes this way :

```
Scenario: Search for item after disabling the javascript
Given I am a ACUST 
When I disable the javascript
And I have entered a text 'dress' string to search for that matches a product
Then The relevant search results for the 'dress' will be returned
```

My code is as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using Hof.Web.Tests.UIAutomation.Pages;
using Hof.Web.Tests.UIAutomation.Helper;
using Hof.Components.Common;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

  public class SearchSteps : Steps  

    {  
        private static readonly string Url = ConfigHelper.GetValue<string>("tset.Web.BaseUrl.QA3") + "/product";  
        public IWebDriver driver;  

        public SearchSteps()  
        {  
            WebBrowser.driverType = "MF";  
            driver = WebBrowser.Current;  
        }  


[Given(@"I am a ACUST")]
        public void GivenIamAAnonymousCustumer()
        {
            var hp = new HeaderPage(driver);
            GenericFunctions.NavigateToURL(Url);//In Future it will be changed to Homepage URL
            Console.WriteLine("Account Name:= " + hp.Lnk_SignInOrRegister.Text);
            Assert.IsTrue(hp.Lnk_SignInOrRegister.Text.Trim().Equals("Sign in or Register"),"Err! User is not anonymous. Please Log out");
        }

[When(@"I disable the javascript")]
public void WhenIDisableTheJavascript()
{
    driver.Close();  //closes previous browser session which has javascript enabled
    FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();  
    p.SetPreference("javascript.enabled", false);  
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(p);  
    var hp = new HeaderPage(driver);  
    GenericFunctions.NavigateToURL(Url);  
}

[When(@"I have entered a text '(.*)' string to search for that matches a product")]
        public void WhenIHaveEnteredATextStringToSearchForThatMatchesAProduct(string strPrdToSearch)
        {
            var hp = new HeaderPage(driver);
            hp.searchForProduct(strPrdToSearch);
        }

[Then(@"The relevant search results for the '(.*)' will be returned")]
        public void ThenTheRelevantSearchResultsForTheWillBeReturned(string prdSearchToVerify)
        {
            var hofProductpage = new ProductPage(WebBrowser.Current);
            hofProductpage.verifyProductSearch(prdSearchToVerify);
        }
```

Code for NavigateToURL:

```
public static void NavigateToURL(string url , IWebDriver driver)  
    {  
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);  
    }
```

The browser opens and also the URL is navigated with javascript disabled form, but the next steps are failing :

```
And I have entered a text 'dress' string to search for that matches a product
Then The relevant search results for the 'dress' will be returned
```

Code to TearDown :

```
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCleanupAttribute()]
        public virtual void ScenarioTearDown()
        {
            testRunner.OnScenarioEnd();
        }
```

And further

```
OnScenarioEnd()  invokes  void OnScenarioEnd();
```

error i get is :
**System.InvalidOperationException: No session ID specified**
**TestCleanup method Hof.Web.Tests.UIAutomation.FeatureFiles.Feature.ScenarioTearDown threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: No session ID specified.**

Comment: So the problem lives in `GenericFunctions.NavigateToURL(Url);`. What's the code in there?

Comment: If you want your question to be answered you should provide the code in `GenericFunctions.NavigateToURL(Url);` so some reasoning about what is happening in there can be made

Comment: @SamHolder : I have added the code to NavigateToURL

Comment: @Arran: I have added the code to NavigateToURL

Comment: @ArpanBuch please post the contents of `Hof.Web.Tests.UIAutomation.FeatureFiles.Feature.ScenarioTearDown` as that seems to be where the problem is happening

Comment: @SamHolder : have a look. Hope thats the correct thing i have pasted or thats the thing u asked.

Comment: seems like a problem related to selenium. try replacing `driver.close()` with `driver.quit()`.

Comment: @SamHolder is there any other way than passing the driver in the NavigateToURL() ?

Comment: @SamHolder 2 instances of browser are opening. i think one with firefox profile and another new firefoxdriver. not sure though, why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that within your navigate method, it refers to a different driver instance.

Notice the `_driver` in that navigate method.

You will need to pass in the instance you've declared:

```
public static void NavigateToURL(string url, IWebDriver driver)  
{  
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);  
}
```

Comment: +1 or set the static `_driver` instance to be the new instance

Comment: @Arran now the url is being navigated but the next step it throws error.. The next scenario step doesnt happen.  See my question , i have updated the complete code.....Thanks..

Comment: Have updated the code and added all the 4 steps, given when and then and their codes..please do have a look!!

Comment: 2 instances of browser are opening.  i think one with firefox profile and another new firefoxdriver.  not sure though, why.

Comment: You've got a step where you are closing one browser and reopening another. So it's expected, no....?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Arran and Sam, I am through to the solution.