# Using wait.until throws System.InvalidOperationException: No session ID specified

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have many test cases, where I need to wait until the page is loaded. I'm using explicit wait as the load times vary.

```
WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
_wait.Until(D => D.Title);
```

It throws No session ID exception. I have a table that takes time to load in the page, so I tried using

```
 _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("table")));
```

Even this throws the same error. The tests pass when I run each one individually and running all of them as suite raises this exception.

```
private static void InitialUpload(string filename)
    {
        SDDirectPage.filePath = filename;
        SDDirectPage.filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SDDirectPage.filePath);
        SDDirectPage.UploadButton.Click();
        Drivers._driverInstance.SwitchTo();
        SDDirectPage.FileReference = SDDirectPage.filename;
        SDDirectPage.UploadTheFile();

        //Check whether 404 occurred or the uploading file is smooth
        if (Drivers._driverInstance.Title == "404 - File or directory not found.") //A bug at the moment, it uploads corrupted files most of the times.
        {
            Assert.Fail("404 error occurred. File might be corrupted or file mightnot be in the specified location..!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Drivers._driverInstance.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
          //  SDDirectPage._wait.Until(D => D.Title);
            SDDirectPage._wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("table")));

            Assert.AreEqual(SDDirectPage.filename + " - SmartDebit Front End Portal", Drivers._driverInstance.Title);
        }
    }
```

This is the function where I'm getting the exception. In some test cases, I have Assert.AreEqual, where I compare the titles. In those test cases, **driver.Title** raises the same error.

Here is the exception:

```
Test FullName:  SDTestAutomation.SDDirectPage_Tests.FixInvalidRows_Search
Test Source:    c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\SDDirectPage_Tests.cs : line 249
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:02:19.2199494

Result Message: 

Test method SDTestAutomation.SDDirectPage_Tests.FixInvalidRows_Search threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: No session ID specified
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByTagName(String tagName)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<TagName>b__18(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass13.<ElementIsVisible>b__12(IWebDriver driver)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   at SDTestAutomation.SDDirectPage_Tests.InitialUpload(String filename) in c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\SDDirectPage_Tests.cs:line 483
   at SDTestAutomation.SDDirectPage_Tests.FixInvalidRows_Search() in c:\Git\AutomationTest\automationtest\AutomationTest\SDTestAutomation\SDDirectPage_Tests.cs:line 250
```

Here is the drivers class:

```
 public class Drivers
{
    static string path = @"C:\SmartDebit\SmartDebitTestAutomation\SmartDebitFramework\DriverResources\";

    public static IWebDriver _driverInstance { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize(string browser)
    {
        if (browser == "FF")
        {
            _driverInstance = new FirefoxDriver();
            _driverInstance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
        }

        if (browser == "IE")
        {
            _driverInstance = new InternetExplorerDriver(path);
            _driverInstance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
        }

        if (browser == "Chrome")
        {
            _driverInstance = new ChromeDriver(path);
            _driverInstance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
        }

    }
}
```

Code for initialising the browser instance:

```
[ClassInitialize]
    public static void BrowserInstance(TestContext t)
    {
        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage.Init("FF");
        loginPage.Goto("url of the application");
        Assert.AreEqual("Login Page", Drivers._driverInstance.Title, "Login page titles doesn't match");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        try
        {
            Login();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex);
            Assert.Fail("ValidLogin() test failed in HomePage_Tests.cs");
            loginPage.QuitBrowser();
        }
    }

    private static void Login()
    {
        loginPage.LoginName = "username";
        loginPage.Password = "password";
        loginPage.LoginButton();
        SDDirectPage._wait.Until(d=>Drivers._driverInstance.Title);
        Assert.AreEqual("Home Page - Front End Portal", Drivers._driverInstance.Title, "Home page title doesn't match");
        Assert.IsTrue(HomePage.loggedInUserText.Contains("username"));
    }
```

I'm using Firefox 43.0.2
Could someone help be to overcome this situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`System.InvalidOperationException: No session ID specified occurs` when you don't have valid driver instance in the method.

Please check `Drivers._driverInstance` is properly instantiated in your code. If possible post the `Drivers` class' relevant portions in the question.

Refer another SO question where the same problem is discussed: [Disabling browser javascript with Selenium webdriver + specflow + c# + Pageobject + pagefactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917530/disabling-browser-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-specflow-c-sharp-page)

Comment: I have added the drivers class. Please let me know if you need any more code samples.

Answer (score 0):

I am basically from Java, but observing the code and exception, i am excepting WebDriverWait is defined in SDDirectPage and  calling here.right?

```
   SDDirectPage._wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("table")));
```

When you are calling defined wait method, you are not passing webdriver instance here. So i am expecting on switching to this method driver loosing the session. For sake of confirm, can you try executing the same by commenting this wait line (and my use something equivalent to Thread.sleep(5000) in Java for once to check this issue)

Thanks

Comment: I added the code for creating the browser instance. I tried using an implicit wait. It passes some of the tests. All my tests are getting the issue where I have wait.until.

Comment: instead of this SDDirectPage._wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.TagName("table"))); use something like this (in java)  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_to_search_textbox")));

Comment: I declared the wait element globally and using it when required. WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(Drivers._driverInstance, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)); I'll try changing from ElementIsVisible to VisibilityOfElementLocated. Hope I can use Tagname instead of Xpath. The issue is, the table takes a min of 30 secs to more than 2mins sometimes. That's the reason I wanted to use until instead of an implicit wait.

Comment: I have tried Using **ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("table") and ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("table")**.  Still getting the same issue with wait.until.

Comment: Please see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html. i hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you that's useful information. wait.until didn't work for me, so I wrote a method with a for loop. As of now I didn't see the session ID issue. Ran the tests once. Should run tests multiple times. Though I'm getting other issues which I have to look into but hope I don't get Session ID issue. As you said, driver loosing the session might be the reason for the issue. I'm a junior and no help, finding it difficult to debug the issue. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Its good to know issue is resolved. Basically I from Java, I can help in depth in java perspective..